# Why does Netbeans IDE look terrible with X forwarding over ssh?

Tags: netbeans, ssh, x11, x11-forwarding

I like the Netbeans IDE and have been using it for many years. Sometimes I am forced to run it on a remote machine, which I access using ssh with X forwarding.

Whenever I do this, all the text looks **TERRIBLE!** The fonts are ugly, jaggy, pixelated, and sometimes hard to read. The common solution for adding `-J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd` to the default settings in `netbeans.conf` makes fonts look better, but it causes a **HUGE** performance drop - the IDE responds so slowly that it is practically unusable.

What can I do? Must I choose between decent performance or readable text? Can't I have both?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it is indeed possible to have good performance and good fonts at the same time. I had a really hard time finding this answer, so I put it here on stackoverflow in the hope of making other Netbeans users' lives easier.

The magic trick is the `xrender` option to the JVM. It changes something about how the java runtime renders text so that the performance drop I saw with font smoothing completely disappeared!

Just add `-J-Dsun.java2d.xrender=true -J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on` to the settings line in netbeans.conf (Usually /usr/local/netbeans-X.Y/etc/netbeans.conf), and enjoy pretty fonts and good performance!

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html
Tested on RHEL remote machine running Netbeans 8.2.

PS: `-J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on` turns on font AA without subpixel hinting. This is my personal preference. You might want to try `gasp` or `lcd` to see which one you like better. The link lists all the available options.

Comment: I'm using OpenJDK Version 1.2.0_121. The xrender flag doesn't seem to help with other JVMs.